# why segmentation fault occurs when using a window in a QSharedPointer?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, segmentation-fault, qsharedpointer

I am developing a gui proram using Qt 4.7.4 (64 bit). I have tried to isolate the problem as follows:

I have a window: `class PreferencesWindow : public QMainWindow` and in another class I initialize and show it as

```
QSharedPointer<PreferencesWindow> pPreferencesWindow = QSharedPointer<PreferencesWindow>(new PreferencesWindow());
pPreferencesWindow->show();
```

it is all good, then I close the window either by pressing `ESC` or clicking the `x` button on the window. And then I call

```
QApplication::quit();
```

to terminate the whole program. It terminates but gives a segmentation fault just before terminating.

The question here is why it terminates cleanly when I use regular pointer instead of  `QSharedPointer` and how to use `QSharedPointer` properly **in this case**?

Comment: A few things come to mind:
Does it crash when `QSharedPointer` goes out of scope or immediately upon `QApplication::quit();`?
Do you really need a Shared Pointer there?  Would a scoped pointer work?

Comment: When I debug after calling `QApplication::quit()` it goes deep into qt library codes then I get lost so I can't say much about whether it goes out the scope or not. But I really need a managed pointer since somethimes I manually delete the window. But I haven't tried scopedPointer. Anyways I am now curious about 'why' it is in this way.

Comment: You're destroying something twice.  When the window is destroyed by quit, X etc, it's done.  There's no more reason to delete anything.  I am probably wrong about the scoped pointer.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill is right about his answer(2nd paragraph). and I think the window gets deleted when `QApplication::quit()` is called not when closed by pressing 'x'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that when you close the window, the data structure pointed to by `pPreferencesWindow` is deleted without the `QSharedPointer`'s knowledge. When the `QSharedPointer` itself is later destroyed, it double-deletes the window, and you get the segfault.

Basically, as with all shared pointer implementations, either everybody plays, or nobody does. Since the Qt internals will never know you're using a smart pointer to manage the window, you can't use one. This is a blessing in disguise, however; it means that Qt itself takes possession of the pointer and agrees to manage it for you, so you don't need a smart pointer after all!

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert with Qt but my first thoughts would be that `QMainWindow` deletes itself upon destruction and the `QSharedPointer` object will also delete the object when it's destroyed (i.e. the object is `delete`d twice).  If this is true you don't need to use the `QSharedPointer` at all.

EDIT: It [looks like](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close) the `QtWidget` `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag will cause the behaviour I have described.

Comment: hi, about your edit I can say that I don't set the flag and it is false by default afaik